# pickadate назначение переменной onSet

Tags: javascript, jquery, дата

Использую библиотеку **pickadate** для выбора даты в форме.

В функции `onSet` произвожу небольшие расчеты.

```
onSet: function(context) {
 driverAge = Math.round((new Date().getTime() - new Date(context.select).getTime())/1000/60/60/24/365);
}
```

При выборе даты мышкой - все нормально, в переменную назначается значение.
Но при выборе даты клавишей <kbd>Enter</kbd> - переменная принимает вид `NAN`.

Comment: Что у вас приходит в `context` когда кликаете мышкой и когда клавишей **Enter**? Сделайте `console.log(context)` перед вычислением ваших расчетов, посмотрим, что там хоть приходит.

Comment: @DenisBubnov При клике мышкой в `context = {select: 1007661600000}`
При Enter `context = {select{date:1;day:6;month:11;obj:Sat Dec 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0600 (Северная Центр. Азия (зима)) {};pick:1007143200000;year:2001}}`. И, в принципе, все на свои места встало. Отследить событие, которым выбрана дата и забрать значение из объекта одним из двух способов. Спасибо.

Comment: Вот и замечательно, что решение нашлось. Вы напишите свой ответ тогда с пояснениями, что, как и почему, чтобы ваш вопрос был полезен на ресурсе SO :)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что при выборе даты клавишей формируется объект `context.select`, содержащий все данные о дате.
А при выборе даты мышью мы получаем `context.select` в виде неформатированной даты (длинное число).

Соответственно, нужно проверить, что мы получаем в результате функции `onSet`:

```
if( (typeof context.select === "object") && (context.select !== null) ) {
 // Выбрали дату клавишей Enter, получили объект
}
else {
 // Выбрали мышью, получили число
}
// или
else if(typeof context.select === "number"){
 // Выбрали мышью, получили число
}
```